# How to evaluate the passed prop to the styled component using react and typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to add a background color to the styled component div if state active is true.

i am doing it like so

```
function Main() {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
    return (
        <ChildComponent 
            active={active}/>
    );
}


const ChildComponent = styled.div<{ active?: boolean }>`
    height: 100%;
    ${({ active }) => active && 'background-color: grey';}
`;
```

This works fine. but instead of just passing string grey to background color i want to pass props like below.

```
const ChildComponent = styled.div<{ active?: boolean }>`
    height: 100%;
    ${({ active }) => active && 'background-color:'${(props: any) => 
    props.theme.colors.grey.light3}};

`;
```

This is not the right syntax to do it. could someone help me fix this thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can nest template literals within template literals as long as they're located inside an interpolated expression block (`${...}`).

So your code should look like this:

```js
const ChildComponent = styled.div<{ active?: boolean }>`
    height: 100%;
    ${({ active, ...props }) => active && `background-color: ${(props: any) => 
    props.theme.colors.grey.light3}`};

`;
```

Comment: hmm after approving realised that the background-color doesnt get applied using props.

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, didn't notice you already destructured props with `({ active })` instead of just passing `(props)`. You can correct this by turning your param to `({ active, ...props })` which will ensure the rest of your props (apart from `active`) are available in the `props` object. I updated my answer to reflect this. Also, make sure your theme is available and properly set up.